# I am not able to update 'shop_table' table value for specifice row using hibernate local session factory object?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

If, I am printing the session object, desired output is not correct i.e. -

```
SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7164ee40 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2d80b7f deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@560d3d76 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@10fbc8b2 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@463b2203 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@47a5a48 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3b23213c collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@75d3c0b2 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])
```

I think valuable if print like this-

```
SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.mode
l.Entity#1]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[
] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[]])
```

My class for Shop is-

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "shops")
public class Shop {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "shop_domain")
    private String shopDomain;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Timestamp orderSyncDate;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "shop", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private NetsuiteConfig netsuiteConfig;
```

I am simply set some data to shop class object, trying to save in DB 
, object hold ID i.e. already exist in DB , query as -
session factory.getCurrentSession().update(shop);
this actually not update the value in db, I don't know the reason, why?

Answer (score 1):

You must commit your update for the changes to propagate into the DB:

```
...
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(shop);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().commit();
...
```

References:

- [Hibernate Session merge, update, save, saveOrUpdate, persist example](https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example#hibernate-update)
- [Hibernate Lifecycle (for Baeldung)](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate)

Comment: @Autowired
 public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
  HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
  txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
  System.out.println(txManager);
  return txManager;
 }

Comment: @ManuSingh : what is the purpose of these two comments?